# You cannot add or change a record because a related record is required vb.net

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, relationships

I know this question has been asked numerous times, but the situations people had were slightly different each time, or lacked enough detail, or the explanation for the problem lacked specific detail that I could understand the solution.

So here is my thing. I've got a combobox called "StatesComboBox" in a form that takes in customer data. This form is bound to a table called "States" in an ms access database file. So whatever states are in that table are reflected in the StatesComboBox.

In my access database file, I've got a table that stores the customer data called "CustomerData". One of the fields in it is called "customerstate", which stores the "StatesComboBox" selection made by the user.

I have connected the "States" table to the "CustomerData" table with a relationship. It connects the States table to the "customerstate" field. This is a one-to-many relationship, and I have checked off on the enforce referential integrity, cascade add and cascade delete options.

Now, when I enter data in the form and hit my register button, I get the message stated above - "You cannot add or change a record because a related record is required in table 'States'". But when I go back to access, delete the relationship between "States" and "CustomerData", the data gets stored just fine.

But I need to enforce limitations on the states selected... What am I doing wrong? What can I do to address this? Thank you.

Comment: Does your [States] table have more than one column, say, [StateCode] with values like "NY" and "OH", and [StateName] with values like "New York" and "Ohio"?

Comment: Show your table design and relationship. (There is no cascade add, just cascade update/delete).

Comment: Hi guys, the state table just contains one column, with different states. I just have a handful of states listed, with their abbreviated code - "NY", "OH", etc. And yes, I meant to say cascade update, not cascade add. How can I show the relationship here? Can I screenshot the Relationships page on Access and paste it here?

Comment: I tried adding screenshots of Access, but it said I need a reputation of at least 10 to do put images in my posts... Urgh.

Comment: If you are allowed to post links then you could upload images to someplace like http://imageshack.us/ and then post the links here.

Comment: Hi guys, I was able to solve my problem. When I selected a State from the combobox and passed that selection into my insert query, it wasn't storing the state's name, but some combobox reference (Systems.DataView or something). So to address this,  I changed every reference in my sql statement from "combobox.SelectedItem.ToString" to "combobox.Text". The right data got saved to the database, and thus the integrity of the relationship was maintained. Thanks for the help guys :)